# Find and return a specific area of a text

Tags: python-2.7

Hello everyone and happy new year! I have a text from which I like to return a specific area from a specific string using a python script!
This is the text I have

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
start)
    ulimit -s 1024
    /usr/bin/oscam --config-dir /etc/tuxbox/config/oscam --daemon --pidfile /tmp/oscam.pid --restart 2 --utf8
    ;;
stop)
    kill `cat /tmp/oscam.pid` 2> /dev/null
    ;;
restart|reload)
    $0 stop
    sleep 1
    $0 start
    ;;
version)
    echo "svn8631"
    ;;
info)
    echo "oscam svn8631"
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 start|stop|restart"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

from the text above I need to create a python command that always returns only what is written where the **oscam svn8631** is written between the quotes! So far the only thing I managed to do is return another area of this text using this code

```
try:
    f = open("/etc/init.d/softcam", "r")
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
except:
    content = ""
contentInfo = content.split("\n")
if (content != ""):
    for line in contentInfo:
        if line.__contains__("usr/bin/"):
            idex = line.index("n/")
            line = line[(idex + 2):]
            return line
```

This of course returns what's after the **usr/bin** text, and I need another area which comes after the word **info)**. Can anyone help me please? I don't know how to make my script read this specific area I need! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand your question, please write down the expected output of the code.

Comment: The output had to be oscam svn8631, my question is answered, thank you so very much for your contributions!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `content` variable that you have created, the 
"oscam svn8631" text can be extracted with:

```
for chunk in content.split(";;"):
    if chunk.strip().startswith('info)'):
        return chunk.split('"')[1]
```

The natural way to break up a bash `case` statement is by splitting it on ";;".  Then, we identify the `info` section (`chunk.strip().startswith('info)')`) and select the first quoted string in that section (`chunk.split('"')[1]`).

Comment: My friend you are PURE GENIUS! I could never think of a chunk function  to split between the ";;" parts! You didn't make my day, you made my year!!! Bow down to you!